# Probability that a randomly selected integer point lies in a sphere

Tags: probability

Suppose $r>1$ be the radius of an $n-$ dimensional sphere centered at the origin, where $r$ is large enough to contain some integral points. Suppose that $\Lambda$ is an $n-$ dimensional lattice with determinant $d$. Assume we have a uniform distribution on the lattice points over $\mathbb{Z}^n$ so that the probability that  a randomly chosen integer point is a lattice point is $\dfrac{1}{d}$. I want to calculate the probability that a randomly chosen integer point is inside the sphere and at the same time a lattice point in $\Lambda$. Any hint or any reference to related literature will be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what a 'randomly selected integer point' is, but anyway your question is probably closely related to this classical problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem

Comment: (I don't believe your question deserves downvotes. However, you can improve your question by specifying your distribution over points and searching around this site for some related questions.)

Comment: Let's assume that the distribution is uniform

Comment: But uniform over what?

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope it's clear now. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: It's still unclear. Do you know that there is no uniform distribution on the integers? Perhaps that is the confusion.  You can, however, talk about density https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density, but the density of any bounded set in the lattice is zero.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt Ohh I see. Since $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is an infinite set, then it seems that the sensible answer is zero. Maybe I can rephrase the problem: instead of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, replace it by a bounded $n-$dimensional cube containing the sphere. Does that make sense now?

Comment: Yes, then it would make sense to restrict to integer points in $[-r,r]^n$, or similar. In that case, the problem for the integer lattice in the plane is basically the same as the Gauss circle problem that I linked to. According to this https://awwalker.com/2017/03/07/lattice-points-in-high-dimensional-spheres/ the problem is actually easier in higher dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, patience and feedback @LorenzoNajt!

Comment: You're very welcome. :-)